# CSS child bigger than parent allowed?

Tags: css, w3c

Quick question.

I know i can make child div bigger than parent, but is it allowed by w3c? Is it against some rules? Any performance problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many cases where you would need an overflow in the parent `div`, with a larger child `div`: for example, a fixed-position content frame.

And there should be no performance impediment; it should be around the same as rendering the child `div` as a sibling of the parent.

Answer (score 3):

If this was not permitted by the standards, then the standards wouldn't define an [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow) CSS property.